# Argument 2 passed to App\Event\ChatEvent::construct() must be an instance of App\User

Tags: laravel

I am using Event and listeners for real time chat application in laravel. For that i am trying to send message form controller to ChatEvent and from ChatEvent to Pusher. So, Whenever i try to hit the localhost:8000/send i get this error.

[image]

Error:
[image: Error is here]

Chat Controller this is where i use ChatEvent class:
[image: Chat Controller this is where i use ChatEvent class]

Comment: Please show the code of controller named `ChatCo`.

Comment: Please share code, where you are using ChatEvent class.

Comment: @LuckySaini I have included Chat controller and i have used my ChatEvent there.

Comment: Check in controller, I think user is coming null. That's why you getting this issue.

Comment: before calling the event in Chat Controller, `dd` the `$user` to check if you are receiving null from the query

Comment: @LuckySaini Oh i see!! but how am i supposed to sort it out.

Comment: @LuckySaini Fixed!! i was not logged in !!! And that was the problem

Comment: Oh..... Great  